# Using jndi connect LDAP in SSL mode ,how to program client certificate in java code?

Tags: ssl, ldap, client-certificates

following is my connect LDAP code,I have already import the CA cert to the "C:/ca.keystore" file, but I want to create a mutual SSL ,so how to program the client cert in my code?

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://127.0.0.1:636/");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, LDAPConfig.getSECURITY_PRINCIPAL()); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, LDAPConfig.getSECURITY_CREDENTIALS());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/ca.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "123456");
ctx =  new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way as for JSSE. Just set the system properties javax.net.ssl.keyStore/keyStorePassword appropriately.